# Retrofit: cancel call if there is no network

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Actually i'm having an issue with my app when i'm using a Device with *radio frequencies*. If the device is out of radio range but trying to send a file i'm getting the onFailure where i'm saying to the user that there is not network but the **MAIN ISSUE** is that as soon as the device return in the radio range so it return in the network it sent anyway the file i was trying to send when i was out of network.

So i would be able to cancel the call onFailure but trying to put call.cancel(); onFailure doesn't worked.

How can i solve that problem?

Answer (score 3):

You could extent the Callback class to create your own class CancellableCallback like this:

```
public class CancellableCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

    private Callback<T> callback;

    private boolean canceled;

    private CancellableCallback() {}

    public CancellableCallback(Callback<T> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
        canceled = false;
    }

    public void cancel() {
        canceled = true;
        callback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void success(T o, Response response) {
        if (!canceled) {
            callback.success(o, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        if (!canceled) {
            callback.failure(error);
        }
    }
```